# Given two decks of cards what is the probability to draw a king, and heart card

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I thought maybe to separate it into two options,

1) A heart King and a heart card

2) Not a heart king and a heart card

I figured the probability for option 2 is
$$\left(\frac{6}{104} \cdot \frac{26}{104}\right) \cdot 2$$ 
We have $6$ cards of kings which are not heart kind, and we have $26$ heart kind of cards. Since there is no importance to the order of the draw we multiply it by $2$.

From here, I got stuck. I could not manage to calculate the probability for option 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Are we drawing from two separate decks or two decks that have been combined into one pile?

Comment: They are combined

Answer (score 1):

> If two standard decks are combined, what is the probability of selecting a heart and a king that is not a heart?

**Method 1:**  There are 
$$\binom{104}{2}$$
ways to choose two cards from the $2 \cdot 52 = 104$ cards in the combined decks.

To be successful, we must choose one of the $26$ hearts and one of the $6$ kings that is not a heart in the combined deck, which can be done in 
$$\binom{26}{1}\binom{6}{1}$$
ways.

Thus, 
$$\Pr(\text{heart and king that is not a heart}) = \frac{\dbinom{26}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{104}{2}}$$

**Method 2:**  We correct your method.

The probability of choosing a heart, then choosing a king that is not a heart from the remaining $103$ cards is 
$$\Pr(H)\Pr(\color{red}{K\diamondsuit}~\text{or}~K\clubsuit~\text{or}~K\spadesuit \mid H) = \frac{26}{104} \cdot \frac{6}{103}$$
The probability of choosing a king that is not a heart, then choosing a heart from the remaining $103$ cards is 
$$\Pr(\color{red}{K\diamondsuit}~\text{or}~K\clubsuit~\text{or}~K\spadesuit)\Pr(H \mid \color{red}{K\diamondsuit}~\text{or}K\clubsuit~\text{or}~K\spadesuit) = \frac{6}{104} \cdot \frac{26}{103}$$
Hence,
$$\Pr(\text{heart and king that is not a heart}) = 2 \cdot \frac{26 \cdot 6}{104 \cdot 103}$$

> If two standard decks are combined, what is the probability of selecting a king of hearts and a heart?

There are two types of favorable cases.  Both kings of hearts are selected or a king of hearts is selected and another heart is selected.

> There is $\binom{2}{2} = 1$ way to select both kings of hearts.  There are $\binom{2}{1}\binom{24}{1}$ ways to select one king of hearts and one of the other $24$ hearts in the combined decks.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is $$\binom{2}{2} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{24}{1}$$ Thus, $$\Pr(\text{king of hearts and a heart}) = \frac{\dbinom{2}{2} + \dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{24}{1}}{\dbinom{104}{2}}$$

Comment: >>To be successful, we must choose one of the 26 hearts and one of the 6 kings that is not a heart in the combined deck - but what if both of the king of hearts are drawn?

Comment: @Cato Notice that I answered the second question first since the OP only attempted the second question.  The second question asks for the number of ways to select a heart and a king that is not a heart, so it is not possible to select both kings of hearts in that question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, think of it like this: you have the first $26$ natural numbers, and you must pick two such that you have at least one of $1$ and $2$. How many ways can you do this? Once you've done this, just assume that cards $1$ and $2$ are the two kings of hearts. Then add this number to the number of ways in which you can get a king not belonging to hearts, and a hearts card. Divide by the total number of ways in which you can pick any two cards.

PS: I'm assuming that the option of having just one king of hearts with some other random card does not satisfy the condition of a king and a heart card?

Answer (score 0):

use a tree

first draw

A draw King (not hearts) = 6/104

B King hearts = 2 / 104

C Hearts, not king of hearts = 24/104

then thinking in each case what you need to complete

for A - you need any of 26 hearts
for B - you need any of 5 kings or 24 hearts (excluding king of hearts already counted)
for C - you need any of the 8 kings

A x 26 / 103 + B x (4 + 25) / 103 + C x 8 / 103 = 203/5356